# Как правильно написать поле для редактирования информации?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ооп

Есть какая-либо информация и кнопка "Редактировать", нужно сделать так, чтобы при клике не кнопку, поле можно было отредактировать.

Мои наработки:

```js
function InfoChange(btnEvent, inputsToChange, classToBlock, buttonTextChange) {
  this.btnEvent = document.querySelector(btnEvent);
  this.inputsToChange = document.querySelectorAll(inputsToChange);
  this.classToBlock = classToBlock;
  this.buttonTextChange = buttonTextChange;
  this.currentBtnText = this.btnEvent.textContent;
  var _this = this;

  var buttonAttr = function() {
   this.btnEvent.setAttribute('data-status', 'unactive');
  };
  buttonAttr();
  
  this.btnEvent.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var btnAttribute =  _this.btnEvent.getAttribute('data-status');
    if (btnAttribute == 'unactive') {
      _this.btnEvent.setAttribute('data-status', 'active');
      _this.btnEvent.textContent = _this.buttonTextChange;
    } else {
      _this.btnEvent.setAttribute('data-status', 'unactive');
      _this.btnEvent.textContent = _this.currentBtnText;
    }
    
    for(var i = 0; i < _this.inputsToChange.lenght; i++) {
      if(!_this.inputsToChange[i].classList.contains(classToBlock)) {
       _this.inputsToChange[i].classList.add(classToBlock);
      } else {
       _this.inputsToChange[i].classList.remove(classToBlock);
      };
    }
  });
};

var changeInputs = new InfoChange('button', 'input', 'unactive', 'Сохранить');
```

```css
.unactive {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<h1>Name</h1>
<input type="text" data-inp='change' class='unactive' placeholder='some' disable>
<h1>Color</h1>
<input type="text" data-inp='change' class='unactive' placeholder='some' disable>
<button>Редактировать</button>
```

Старался писать в ООП стиле, т.к. будет несколько кнопок, каждая из которых отвечает за свои поля.

Сам вопрос собственно в том, как правильно заблокировать поля, чтобы в них нельзя было писать, и чтобы то, что было написано сохранялось после нажатия на кнопку "Сохранить";

Comment: только не disable, а disabled